# Is It a bug for liftweb TimeHelpers: 60.minutes not equals 1.hour

Tags: scala, lift

```
scala> import net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers._

import net.liftweb.util.TimeHelpers._

scala> 60.minutes  == 1.hour

res14: Boolean = false

scala>
```

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order in the equality? From the source it looks like `.minutes` returns a Period, `.hours` returns a Duration (subtype of Period), so if the equals polymorphism stuff is bonked...

Comment: Oh, hmm. It seems that has changed.... sometime. Compare https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/core/util/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/util/TimeHelpers.scala with http://olim7t.github.com/liftweb-2.0-release-sxr/net/liftweb/util/TimeHelpers.scala.html, for instance. It might be specific to a particular release? At the very least, specify the *exact* Lift version used -- and good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

According to David Pollak (who should know), this is due to joda time. See [Is It a bug of liftweb TimeHelpers: 60.minutes not equals 1.hour](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/b8WncRJkI2c).

The solution is to convert to Duration and then compare the two values. From [Period.java](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/Period.java):

> The definition of a period also affects the equals method. A period of
>   1 day is not equal to a period of 24 hours, nor 1 hour equal to 60
>   minutes. This is because periods represent an abstracted definition of
>   a time period (eg. a day may not actually be 24 hours, it might be 23
>   or 25 at daylight savings boundary). To compare the actual duration of
>   two periods, convert both to durations using toDuration, an operation
>   that emphasises that the result may differ according to the date you
>   choose.

This solution was provided by andreak, on the above link to the google group thread, and copied here so that others can find it here.

Comment: `res0: Boolean = false`. Also, it’s been a long time since Lift 1.0.

Comment: @Debilski yep, you're right, did a more thorough job this time and edited the answer.